# getting or fetching the Value from an Object Array , from an HashMap

Tags: java

I have got the following Map Structure

**{CDetails=[{"collegeName":"Peters Stanford","collegeLoc":"UK"},{}]}**

I am trying to get the **collegeLoc** value from the above mentioned structure

This is what i tried

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Map < String, Object > empMap = new HashMap < > ();

    JSONObject collegeNameJsonObj = new JSONObject();
    collegeNameJsonObj.put("collegeName", "Peters Stanford");

    JSONObject collegeIdJsonObj = new JSONObject();
    collegeNameJsonObj.put("collegeLoc", "UK");

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.add(collegeNameJsonObj);
    jsonArray.add(collegeIdJsonObj);

    empMap.put("CDetails", jsonArray);


  System.out.println(empMap.entrySet().stream().filter(map->map.getKey().equals("CDetails")).map(map->map.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Struck here , unable to loop / parse further .

how to get the collegeLoc value in this case ? any help would be great .

Comment: Can you get value from JSONObject by key,like `jsonObject.getAsString(key)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code,

```java
empMap
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(map -> map.getKey().equals("CDetails"))
    .forEach(e -> {
            JSONArray jsArray = (JSONArray) e.getValue();
            for (Object jsObject : jsArray) {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsObject;
                if (obj.containsKey("collegeLoc")) {
                    System.out.println(obj.getAsString("collegeLoc"));
                }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be

```
json.getJSONArray("CDetails").getJSONObject(0).getString("slogan")
```

Or, which is better, create a [Value Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) and serialize / deserialize it. It will be much easier to manipulate & navigate with Java class rather than with a pure JSON document.

```
class ValueObject {
  @JsonProperty("CDetails")
  private List<Detail> details;

  static class Detail {
    private String collegeName;
    private String collegeLoc;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If use `net.minidev.json` json lib,try the follow code:

```
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) empMap.get("CDetails");

array.stream().filter(o -> {
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) o;
    return jsonObject.containsKey("collegeLoc");
}).map(o -> {
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) o;
    return jsonObject.getAsString("collegeLoc");
}).forEach(System.out::println);
```